# hline length under title in section

Tags: line-spacing, sections-paragraphs

In my Latex document, I decided to draw a line under each section as follows:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[{\color{coolblack}\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
```

Moreover, at the beginning of the document I inserted a picture at the top right of the document. I used the command wrap picture in order to have my text around this image

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{00mm}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[scale=0.12]{picture.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

However, the length of my line drawn by the title does not adjust and cut my picture (see print screen)
[image]

Therefore, how is it the adjust the length only of this particular section (and leave all other section with a full hline)?

Thanks for your support

PS: here is all the code

```
  % PACKAGES
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper, 10 pt, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=4.1cm, right=1.0cm, top=0.35cm, bottom=0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{scrextend}

% Title format
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [{\color{coolblack}\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}{0ex plus 0ex}



% Title line color
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{coolblack}{RGB}{58, 53, 61}

\begin{document}

% Command label item
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\raise .5ex\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}


% Personal informations and picture
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{00mm}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{hh.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure} 




% Objective
\section{Objective}

\noindent aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa dafsdj dfsajk sdafjashj sdajhsa \

\end{document}
```

Comment: hi ! could you give us a MWE.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here, what is a MWE?

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe

Comment: Thanks a lot, however what do you need exactly? all my code? thanks for your support by the way

Comment: not inevitably all the code but a working part that show your issue

Comment: I just added a print screen to help you understand. See the text with my code breaks perfectly before the image but not the line

Comment: please give the code

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I understand, sorry about that, let me add everything

Comment: Is it okay for you now?

Comment: Your image is not part of the section title, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use `titlesec` together with a `koma`-class, as the warnings in your document say

> Usage of package `titlesec' together(scrartcl) with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.

If you do not use any `koma` specific mechanism, I usually found it easier to change the class, for example to `article`, than to change from titlesec to something else.

Also you should not load packages multiple times, e.g. `titlesec`.

---

Back to your problem, if you replace the `titlerule` with a normal rule with the width `textwidth` it will be as long as your wrapped text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10 pt, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Title format
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [{\color{coolblack}}\vskip-\topskip\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}{0ex plus 0ex}

% Title line color
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{coolblack}{RGB}{58, 53, 61}

\begin{document}

% Personal informations and picture
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{00mm}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{pic}
\end{wrapfigure} 

\section{Objective}
\noindent \lipsum[1]

\section{Another Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help, it works perfectly and that's exactly what I wanted. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Good to hear. A nice day to you too! P.S. If the question is solved for you, consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark ✓.

Answer (score 0):

like this :

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10 pt, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=4.1cm, right=1.0cm, top=0.35cm, bottom=0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\usepackage{mwe}

% Title format
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [{\color{coolblack}\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}{0ex plus 0ex}



% Title line color
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{coolblack}{RGB}{58, 53, 61}

\begin{document}

% Command label item
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\raise .5ex\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}


% Personal informations and picture
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{00mm}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure} 

\vspace*{0cm}

% Objective
\section{Objective}

\noindent aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa dafsdj dfsajk sdafjashj sdajhsa \

\end{document}
```